# pile recursive prime counter python

Tags: python

I need to check a range of numbers, including them, I got this code but I get an error, and it must be pile recursive.

```
def esPrimo(a):
  if (a <2):
    return False;
  for i in range(2,a):
    if a%i == 0:
      return False;
  return True;

def calcularCantidadPrimosEnIntervalo(a, b):

    if(a>b):
      return 0;
    else:
      if(esPrimo(a)):
        return calcularCantidadPrimosEnIntervalo(a+1, b) + 1;
      else:
        calcularCantidadPrimosEnIntervalo(a+1, b); 
print("Numeros Primos: " + calcularCantidadPrimosEnIntervalo(1,7));
```

I get this exception:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: Knowing that `calcularCantidadPrimosEnIntervalo` is returning `None`, and that `None` is the default return value if a `return` is not executed, can you find any paths where you’re not returning a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're missing a `return` statement.** So sometimes your `calcularCantidadPrimosEnIntervalo()` function returns `None` instead of an integer.

This line:

```
else:
    calcularCantidadPrimosEnIntervalo(a + 1, b);
```

...should be:

```
else:
    return calcularCantidadPrimosEnIntervalo(a + 1, b);
```